# Error with calculating of octal system in Python

Tags: python, octal

*Just I check if for example 1 + 2 is equal to 3 so it means 0011 in binary code.*

```
ox_number = 361
output = []

for num in ox_number.split():
  if 1 == num:
    output.append("001")
  elif 1 + 2 == num:
    output.append("011")
  else 1 + 2 + 4 == num:
    output.append("111")

connected = ''.join(output)
rever_ = reversed(connected)

print(rever_)
```

Comment: You can directly express the number as `{:o}.format(ox_number)`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your integer to and from an octal formatted string by using

```py
your_int = 386
its_octal_is = f"{your_int:o}"
# Equivalent to
its_octal_is = "{:o}".format(your_int)
int_from_octal_string = int("386",8)
```

You might want to have a look at `int` documentation as well as the formatting expressions [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).